# Curing Green Olives

Tags: food-preservation

I picked some beautiful green Manzananillo olives and followed the directions of my preserving guru Pietro Demaio's book by soaking them in fresh water for three days changing the water every 3 days and used an inverted plate to keep them covered by the water. Then you put them in a brine. But before I put them in the brine a lot of them have become a blotchy bruised colour. Is it because I have put them in plastic tubs??? I don't want to use caustic soda. Does anybody have a solution or explanation why they have become blotchy??

Comment: I've never done it, but some quick reading suggests that if you have slightly dried out olives when you start, they're more likely to become blotchy.